# Why do I get a 301 response on HTTP post to Laravel without CSRF token?

Tags: php, laravel, http, post, adyen

I'm trying to set up Adyen notifications in my webshop.
https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/notifications/understand-notifications

When I test the HTTP post with Adyen test page I get a 301 response, but when I test the HTTP post with a custom form the route works.

Route in web.php:
`Route::name('shop.checkout.adyen-notification')->post('/adyen-notification', 'Shop\CheckoutController@adyenNotification');`

Settings in VerifyCsrfToken.php:
`protected $except = ['*/adyen-notification?*'];`

Custom form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://example.com/adyen-notification?originalReference=&reason=&merchantAccountCode=Test&eventCode=NOTIFICATIONTEST&operations=&success=true&paymentMethod=bankTransfer_BE&currency=EUR&pspReference=test_NOTIFICATIONTEST_1&merchantReference=testMerchantRef1&value=11099">
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

I can't figure out why it is giving me a 301 response.

Comment: 301 means "moved permanently". Since you white-listed the CSRF token and we don't see what your controller do, we have no idea what response you should get.  What response do you expect?

Comment: @LobsterBaz My controller just returns a string atm moment for testing. When I submit the form I mentioned it returns the string just fine, but when I send a HTTP post from Adyen test page I get the 301 response.

Comment: 301 is the status, is there data in the response? Since it's a redirect status, where does it redirect to? I'm not familiar with Adyen but could it have anything to do with your local environment not using https?

Comment: @LobsterBaz It is returning the default 301 html from Laravel and is says it moved to the same url as I'm calling. My development environment uses https.

Comment: I never used Adyen but do you need to be in test mode with a test API key? Can your development server be reached from the Internet? Is your Laravel .env APP_URL matching your server URL?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your form action, the closing quotation mark is missing:

```
<form method="post" action="https://example.com/adyen-notification?originalReference=&reason=&merchantAccountCode=Test&eventCode=NOTIFICATIONTEST&operations=&success=true&paymentMethod=bankTransfer_BE&currency=EUR&pspReference=test_NOTIFICATIONTEST_1&merchantReference=testMerchantRef1&value=11099>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Should be:

```
<form method="post" action="https://example.com/adyen-notification?originalReference=&reason=&merchantAccountCode=Test&eventCode=NOTIFICATIONTEST&operations=&success=true&paymentMethod=bankTransfer_BE&currency=EUR&pspReference=test_NOTIFICATIONTEST_1&merchantReference=testMerchantRef1&value=11099">
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: I pasted it wrong here but it is oke. My custom form works so thats not the problem. Only when I post from Adyen I get the 301 response.